# How to make background black of react native camera?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created react native camera but it is looked like this.

[image]

But the problem is the background color of camera action icons are transparent.

This is my code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Image,
  CameraRoll,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import IoniconsIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import EntypoIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import AppText from '_components/appText';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
import normalize from '_utils/fontsize';
let countRecordTime;

const PendingView = () => (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <AppText>Waiting</AppText>
  </View>
);

const takePicture = async (camera) => {
  const options = {quality: 1};
  const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
  console.log(data.uri);
};

const recordVideo = async (
  camera,
  recording,
  seconds,
  setRecording,
  setSeconds,
) => {
  if (camera) {
    if (!recording) {
      startRecording(recording, setRecording, seconds, setSeconds, camera);
    } else {
      stopRecording(camera, setSeconds);
    }
  }
};

const startRecording = async (
  recording,
  setRecording,
  seconds,
  setSeconds,
  camera,
) => {
  setRecording(true);
  console.log('>>>>>> start recording seconds', seconds);
  const cameraConfig = {maxDuration: 20};
  const data = await camera.recordAsync(cameraConfig);
  console.log('>>>>>> data', data);
  setRecording(false);
};

const stopRecording = (camera, setSeconds) => {
  camera.stopRecording();
  setSeconds(0);
};

const secondsToMMSS = (seconds) => {
  console.log('>>>>>> seconds', seconds);
  let m = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  let s = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

  let mDisplay = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : `${m}`;
  let sDisplay = s < 10 ? `0${s}` : `${s}`;
  return `${mDisplay}:${sDisplay}`;
};

const VideoRecording = (props) => {
  const [type, setType] = useState(RNCamera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off);
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (recording) {
      countRecordTime = setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds + 1), 1000);
    }
    if (!recording && countRecordTime) {
      clearInterval(countRecordTime);
    }

    if (seconds === 20 && countRecordTime) {
      clearInterval(countRecordTime);
      setRecording(false);
    }

    return () => {
      if (countRecordTime) {
        clearInterval(countRecordTime);
      }
    };
  }, [recording, seconds]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
        style={styles.preview}
        autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
        type={type}
        flashMode={flashMode}
        faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
        ratio="4:3"
        whiteBalance={RNCamera.Constants.WhiteBalance.auto}
        captureAudio={true}
        androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
          title: 'Permission to use camera',
          message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
          buttonPositive: 'Ok',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        }}
        androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
          title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
          message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
          buttonPositive: 'Ok',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        }}>
        {({camera, status, recordAudioPermissionStatus}) => {
          if (status !== 'READY') {
            return <PendingView />;
          }
          return (
            <>
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 0,
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.capture}
                  onPress={(_) => {
                    switch (flashMode) {
                      case RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off:
                        setFlashMode(RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto);
                        break;

                      case RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto:
                        setFlashMode(RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on);
                        break;

                      case RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on:
                        setFlashMode(RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off);
                        break;
                    }
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={
                      flashMode === RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto
                        ? require('../../assets/img/flashAuto.png')
                        : flashMode === RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on
                        ? require('../../assets/img/flashOn.png')
                        : require('../../assets/img/flashOff.png')
                    }
                    style={{width: 30, height: 30}}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {/* <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => takePicture(camera)}
                  style={styles.capture}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../../assets/img/cameraButton.png')}
                    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity> */}
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.iconContainer}
                  onPress={() =>
                    recordVideo(
                      camera,
                      recording,
                      seconds,
                      setRecording,
                      setSeconds,
                    )
                  }>
                  <EntypoIcon
                    style={styles.icon}
                    size={40}
                    color={recording ? 'red' : 'white'}
                    name="video-camera"
                  />
                  {recording ? (
                    <AppText styles={styles.recordingTime}>
                      {secondsToMMSS(seconds)}
                    </AppText>
                  ) : null}
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.capture}
                  onPress={(_) => {
                    if (type === RNCamera.Constants.Type.back) {
                      setType(RNCamera.Constants.Type.front);
                    } else {
                      setType(RNCamera.Constants.Type.back);
                    }
                  }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../../assets/img/cameraFlipIcon.png')}
                    style={{width: 40, height: 40}}
                    resizeMode={'contain'}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={() => {}}>
                <IoniconsIcon
                  name={'ios-close'}
                  style={styles.closeButtonIcon}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </RNCamera>
    </View>
  );
};

export default VideoRecording;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
  cptureView: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: '20%',
    marginTop: '5%',
  },
  camIcon: {
    color: '#858181',
  },
  iconContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    // paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  recordingTime: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: '#aaaaaab0',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 45 : 10,
    left: 10,
  },
  closeButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    lineHeight: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 58 : 40,
  },
});
```

Can someone help me to make it black? I tried a lot to find out way to do so that. But I could not so if someone can help me it would be grateful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this?

```js
...
<View
style={{
  flex: 0,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: "#000000", //-----------------Here?
}}>
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.capture}
  onPress={(_) => {
    switch (flashMode) {
      case RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off:
        setFlashMode(RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto);
...
```